# Ruby: How to hook onto class methods

Tags: ruby

From: http://cheind.blogspot.com/2008/12/method-hooks-in-ruby.html

I have

```
# Contains methods to hook method calls
module FollowingHook

  module ClassMethods

    private

    # Hook the provided instance methods so that the block 
    # is executed directly after the specified methods have 
    # been invoked.
    #
    def following(*syms, &block)
      syms.each do |sym| # For each symbol
        str_id = "__#{sym}__hooked__"
        unless private_instance_methods.include?(str_id)
          alias_method str_id, sym        # Backup original 
                                          # method
          private str_id                  # Make backup private
          define_method sym do |*args|    # Replace method
            ret = __send__ str_id, *args  # Invoke backup
            block.call(self,              # Invoke hook
              :method => sym, 
              :args => args,
              :return => ret
            )
            ret # Forward return value of method
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # On inclusion, we extend the receiver by 
  # the defined class-methods. This is an ruby 
  # idiom for defining class methods within a module.
  def FollowingHook.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

Then I have a class like so:

```
class User
  def self.get
   #class method
  end
  def name
   #instance method
  end
end
```

In another location/file I reopen the User class and hook into it

```
class User
  include FollowingHooks # include the hook module
  following :name do |receiver, args|
   #do something. This works!!
  end
  following :get do |reciever, args|
   #do something. THIS DOESNT WORK
   # Which is to be expected looking at the FollowingHooks module definition.
  end
end
```

Hooking into any instance methods works. However trying to hook into class methods does nothing, which I get, because the FollowingHooks module doesn't implement it. How would I implement hooks for class methods? I am totally clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the FollowingHook code on `Class` and then call following so that it applies to the class methods.

```
Class.send(:include, FollowingHook)
class User
  class << self
    following :get do |reciever, args|
      # Your awesome code here
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

Here is my complete working solution which followed this suggestion:

```
# Contains methods to hook method calls
module FollowingHook

  module ClassMethods

    private

    # Hook the provided instance methods so that the block 
    # is executed directly after the specified methods have 
    # been invoked.
    #
    def following(*syms, &block)
      syms.each do |sym| # For each symbol
        str_id = "__#{sym}__hooked__"
        unless private_instance_methods.include?(str_id)
          alias_method str_id, sym        # Backup original 
                                          # method
          private str_id                  # Make backup private
          define_method sym do |*args|    # Replace method
            ret = __send__ str_id, *args  # Invoke backup
            block.call(self,              # Invoke hook
              :method => sym, 
              :args => args,
              :return => ret
            )
            ret # Forward return value of method
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, FollowingHook::ClassMethods)
  end
end

class User
  def self.foo
    puts "foo"
  end
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

# You can put this in the class << self block if you prefer that the
# methods only be available on the User class.
Class.send(:include, FollowingHook)

class User
  include FollowingHook
  following :bar do |receiver, args|
    puts receiver.inspect
  end
  class << self
    # If you prefer only the User class include FollowingHooks, use the
    # following instead of including them in Class.
    # include FollowingHook
    following :foo do |receiver, args|
      puts receiver.inspect
    end
  end
end

User.foo #=>
# foo
# User
User.new.bar #=>
# bar
# #<User:0x338d9d>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get "undefined method `following' for #<Class:User>". Which makes sense, since "class << self' will change to a singleton context. Also if somehow this were resolved, it would still hit a hitch at the "define method" call in FollowingHook. Because define_method always defines an instance method and not a class method. I thought of using "define_singleton_method" if the context was a class, but that doesn't quite work either.

Comment: Did you run `Class.send(:include, FollowingHook)`? That is what resolves the "undefined method" problem on instances of `Class`.

Comment: A class is just an instance of Class, so calling `define_method` on a singleton of a Class correctly defines those methods as class methods.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I hadn't actually run `Class.send(:include, FollowingHook)`. Now that I did, it works and is a more elegant solution than creating a separate function for class. This is great!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this works.

```
    def following_c(*syms, &block)
      metaclass = (class << self; self; end)
      syms.each do |sym|
        str_id = "__#{sym}__hooked__"
        unless metaclass.send(:private_instance_methods).include?(str_id)
          metaclass.send :alias_method, str_id, sym        

          metaclass.send :private, str_id                  
          metaclass.send :define_method, sym do |*args|    
            ret = send str_id, *args 
            block.call(self,
              :method => sym, 
              :args => args,
              :return => ret
            )
            ret 
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: YES! It does. I've been trying so many different ways. Nothing worked. This is fantastic! Although I am not sure I understand how. Specifically what does "metaclass = (class << self; self; end)" do?

Comment: since everything in ruby is an object, classes are also objects, so they have a class that defines them. Therefore the term metaclass: A class of a class. And that is a way to get the metaclass. Check this blog post http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html

Comment: and this is what you get from inspect `self.inspect #=> User` and `metaclass.inspect #=> #<Class:User>`

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks for the link and of course for the solution.